# All child components are re-rendered when push to props array

Tags: reactjs

I have an array called `roles` that I loop through and create child components. When I push an item to that array, all the children components are re-rendering (based on the `console.log` in the render method).

I thought that react had smart virtual dom diffing where only changed items update. So why is it that ALL items are re-rendering, even thought all children props remain unchanged when an extra item is appended to the array? Am I doing something wrong where I'm incorrectly updating the array?

https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering!!')
        return <li>{this.props.role.name}</li>;
    }
});


var Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
           roles: [
              {name: 'Admin', i: 0},
              {name: 'Janitor', i: 1},
              {name: 'Teacher', i: 2},
           ]
      }
    },
    addRole: function(){
        var i = this.state.roles.length;
      var newRoles = this.state.roles.slice();
      newRoles.push({name: 'some role', i: i})

        this.setState({
        roles: newRoles
      })
    },
    render: function() {
            var roles = this.state.roles.map(function(role){
            return <Child role={role} key={role.i}/>
        });
        return (
            <ul>
            {roles}
            <button onClick={this.addRole}>Add role</button>
          </ul>);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default React will always re-render everything. There is a life-cycle method called `shouldComponentUpdate` which enables this behaviour (it is always returning `true`).

By making `shouldComponentUpdate` return either true or false depending on what props change you can change this and tell React not to re-render everything, all the time.

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate: function(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.role.name === nextProps.role.name) { 
            return false; 
        }
        return true;
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log('rendering!!')
        return <li>{this.props.role.name}</li>;
    }
});
```

Comment: So you should always try implement `shouldComponentUpdate` for better performance?

Comment: If you have very expensive computations, yes, otherwise no, IMO.

Comment: Last question, if instead of pushing to the array I choose to change the `name` property to something else - why are the `nextProps` and `this.props` the same in the `shouldComponentUpdate` method? see https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/23716/

Comment: The objects within your sliced array are still the same objects, slice doesn't deep clone or copy the objects, it creates a new array for sure but it keeps the objects within.